Go MS Visual Studio Code How can I install go tools without internet connection?
I have 2 computers:

at home with internet connection
at work without internet connection.

I want to learn go language on the both PCs.
I already did the steps:

I worked with Go on my home computer successfully.
I copied folders Go1.23.0 and MS Visual Studio Code to my second computer, but it doesn’t work.
I installed Go extension for MS VSC from .VSIX file.
I created a %GOPATH%
I can’t install Delve debugger and other tools for go, such as gopls, gotests, gomodifytags, impl, goplay, staticcheck.

Where can I find the tools on my home computer?
Where should I copy the tools in MS VC path?
Maybe in Go1.23.0 path?

Are you even supposed to install anything on your work computer? Many company IT departments would prevent that entirely.

I know this is a glib response, but you do not need to have any Go tools to be installed in/with vscode in order to learn how to program Go. All you need is to either grab an MSI installer from https://go.dev/dl/ and install it (but yes, I'm afraid it's not gonna work in properly locked-down environments—as Fildor pointed out) or download a ZIP archive from there and unwrap it anywhere you have access to; you could then add the full path to the "bin" subdirectory of the directory resulting from unpacking to your user's PATH environment variable–in order to make calls to go to just work.

«… to be installed in/with vscode»–I wanted to point out that in order to program in Go, all you need is the go compiler (and the Go standard library) and any program able to edit text files (encoded in UTF-8), so basically even stock Notepad fits. Yes, you won't have all that cool stuff an IDE provides, but then note that if you cannot live w/o this stuff at this point, then you're not learning how to program. In other words, IDEs help, but programming is a distinct activity from using IDEs.

That's an unfortunate a dead end, as there are quite a few dependencies acquiring after the extension installation by the extension itself, which is blocked by your network. You will have to support yourself by digging into the code base, https://github.com/golang/vscode-go
